# Controller Timeout MVC 3.0

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

On page load i get current Datetime , and then I need to redirect user after 1 hour spend on the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't really controller logic unless you were using an async controller to do some async work server side.  Then you could add this async timeout attribute: `[AsyncTimeout(3600000)]`.

Otherwise, I'd do the timeout in javascript/jquery where I'd set a timer and after one hour do redirect in the js or call a controller to handle the redirect.

Comment: What Amurra said. You'll need to implement a javascript timeout on the page.